# redirect single query string htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

Im trying to map this string:

http://www.example.com/component/content/?view=featured

to this url:

http://www.example.com/mynewpage/isreallycool/

I cant seem to find the right rewrite rule to do this. All the ones ive seen are for

http://www.example.com/?view=featured

And im struggling with the folder names

Any helps are much appreciated

Comment: so exactly form the example you give us you want `http://www.example.com/component/featured` to be this `http://www.example.com/component/content/?view=featured` right?

Comment: Sorry, its the other way around http://www.example.com/component/content/?view=featured to http://www.example.com/mynewpage/isreallycool/ (not /component/content/ etc

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^view=featured$ 
RewriteRule ^component/content/?$ /mynewpage/isreallycool/ [L,R]
```

In the htaccess file in your document root.